# Printing the inverse pyramid using alphabets

Tags: python

I need to print a pattern like this:

```
C E G I K
D F H J
E G I
F H
G
```

Here is my code:

Someone please correct this code for me.

```
alpha=ord('C')
for i in range(5,0,-1):
    for j in range(i):
        print(chr(alpha+2),end="")
    print('')
```

My current output is:

```
E E E E E
E E E E
E E E
E E
E
```

Comment: Can anyone help me correct my code to get the desired output?

Comment: Tip: You never change alpha, so alpha + 2 is always the same.

Comment: Its hard to tell the sequence of the expected output. So it won't help

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be `D F H J`?

Comment: is there like any new logic that can be applied to rectify or probably change the code?

Comment: @blhsing right i'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an offset to the ordinal number of `C` based on the the line number and character number:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(*(chr(ord('C') + i + j * 2) for j in range(5 - i)), sep=' ')
```

Comment: Thank you so much i never thought about it this way :))))